# Image transparency level 100% on pageload

Tags: jquery, html, css

Referring to My earlier question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942008/image-transparency-level-fade-on-mouse-over-and-stay-100-on-click/) is it possible to make #bod1 image 100% since i am showing the related text by $('#bod1').click(); on pageload. Below is my code.

CODE

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    var activeOpacity   = 1.0,
        inactiveOpacity = 0.3,
        fadeTime = 350,
        clickedClass = "selected",
        thumbs = "#boardDirectorsImage img";

    $(thumbs).fadeTo(1, inactiveOpacity);

    $(thumbs).hover(
        function(){
            $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
        },
        function(){
            // Only fade out if the user hasn't clicked the thumb
            if(!$(this).hasClass(clickedClass)) {
                $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, inactiveOpacity);
            }
        });
     $(thumbs).click(function() {
         // Remove selected class from any elements other than this
         $(thumbs).removeClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, inactiveOpacity);
       $(this).addClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
     });
});
```

Image listing in HTML:

```
<div id="pageBodyContainerRight">
            <div id="boardDirectorsImage"><img src="images/bod_image1a.jpg" width="171" height="168" id="bod1" class="bod1" /></div>
            <div id="boardDirectorsImage"><img src="images/bod_image2a.jpg" width="171" height="168" id="bod2" class="bod2" /></div>
            <div id="boardDirectorsImage"><img src="images/bod_image3a.jpg" width="171" height="168" id="bod3" class="bod3" /></div>
            <div id="boardDirectorsImage" style="width:169px;"><img src="images/bod_image4a.jpg" width="169" height="168" id="bod4" /></div>

            <div id="boardDirectorsImage"><img src="images/bod_image5a.jpg" width="171" height="168" id="bod5" /></div>
            <div id="boardDirectorsImage"><img src="images/bod_image6a.jpg" width="171" height="168" id="bod6" /></div>
            <div id="boardDirectorsImage"><img src="images/bod_image7a.jpg" width="171" height="168" id="bod7" /></div>
            <div id="boardDirectorsImage" style="width:169px;"><img src="images/bod_image8a.jpg" width="169" height="168" id="bod8" /></div>

            <div id="boardDirectorsImage"><img src="images/bod_image9a.jpg" width="171" height="168" id="bod9" /></div>
            <div id="boardDirectorsImage"><img src="images/bod_image10a.jpg" width="171" height="168" id="bod10" /></div>
            <div id="boardDirectorsImage"><img src="images/bod_image11a.jpg" width="171" height="168" id="bod11" /></div>
            <div id="boardDirectorsImage" style="width:169px;"><img src="images/bod_image11a.jpg" width="169" height="168" id="bod12" /></div>
</div>
```

Finally each image when clicked shows a write up text, here is the code for that:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#bod1').click(); 
});

$('#bod1').click(function() {
  $('#bodInfoContain').html('<p class="bodName">NAME 1</p>'); 
});

$('#bod2').click(function() {
  $('#bodInfoContain').html('<p class="bodName">NAME 2</p>');
});
```

Is this possible? Appreciate any help. Trying to get this last bit of code working for days with research inst helping.

Cheers.

Comment: You cannot have same id for more then one elements, use classes instead.

Comment: You mean the dv ID or the image ID. I have different ids for the image tag, does that make a difference?

Comment: no two elements in a DOM can have same id.